# change Commercetools Product Projection Search sort rules

Tags: commercetools

Good afternoon, the standard sorting in comerstools supports sorting alphabetically. The sorting principle is special characters first, then numbers, then letters. I need records to be returned
A-Z
numbers
specsymbols
and if the record starts with a space, then this space is not taken.

"A"
" B"
"9"
"("

Is it possible to do this with the standard tools of comerstools? The documentation says only about sorting in ascending and descending order. I need to set a different sorting principle.

I'm trying to use the queries described in the documentation

[products-search#sorting](https://docs.commercetools.com/api/projects/products-search#sorting)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the sort feature cannot be customized as you describe.

As mentioned in the documentation, if multiple sort expressions are specified via multiple sort parameters, they are combined into a composed sort where the results are first sorted by the first expression, followed by equal values being sorted according to the second expression, and so on.  This could be helpful to your use case.

https://docs.commercetools.com/api/general-concepts#sorting

Best regards,
Michael